# How to hide the mouse pointer after I finished using a bluetooth mouse?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, mouse

i recently bought a bluetooth mouse for my android tablet (galaxy tab 7 p1000 running gingerbread) and every time I stop using the mouse, the pointer stands where it was, only thing that makes it go away is a reboot.

Is there any way to hide the mouse pointer when the mouse is no longer in use without rebooting?